# handleActive Function is undefined in my component

Tags: reactjs

I have Custom Input component

```
const CustomInput: React.FC<CustomInputProps> = ({ label, handleChange, handleActive, active, children, name, ...otherProps }) => {
    return (
        <IonItem lines='none'>
            {label && (
                <IonLabel
                    position='stacked'
                    className="store-input-label"
                >
                    {label}
                </IonLabel>
            )}

            <IonInput
                {...otherProps}
                name={name}
                onIonChange={handleChange}
                onIonFocus={() => handleActive(name)}
                className={`store-input ${active === name && 'store-input--active'}`}>
                {children}

            </IonInput>
        </IonItem>
    );
}

export default CustomInput;
```

Props types

```
export interface CustomInputProps {
    label?: string,
    handleChange: any,
    handleActive?: any,
    active?: any,
    name?: string,
    value: string | number | null,
    placeholder?: string,
    type?: any,
    children?: any
}
```

I consume the Component Like this

```
        <CustomInput
         name='storeName'
         value={storeName}
         handleChange={handleChange}
         handleActive={(active: any) => setActive(active)}
         active={activeInput}
         placeholder='Please Input your store name'
         />
```

But sometimes I don't want to specified the active and handleActive props. Like This:

```
     <CustomInput
      value={userName}
      handleChange={(e: any) => setUserName(e.details.value)}
      >
```

In here I didn't specified the active and handleActive props but i get an error like this:
**handleActive is not a function**

How to pass this kind of optional function as a props

Comment: can you share your `CustomInputProps` interface?

Comment: @PriyankKachhela I have update the question. You can now check the `CustomInputProps `

Comment: so your are declaring handleActive function as optional but you are using that function without any conditional checking that's why it shows error. You need to add conditional check before calling handleActive function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use condition to check props `handleActive` passed in or not:

```
onIonFocus={() => handleActive && handleActive(name)}
```

Comment: is this is a good practice!? I am not familiar with this kind of component. And trying for the first time

Comment: Of course. This is the best solution I know